# How to show all the worksheets on user form in vba?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I used my code to open up workbook, after I select the workbook, I want to prompt user form which will display all the worksheets which belong to the workbook. Here is my code:

```
Function WorksheetExists(WSName As String) As Boolean
   On Error Resume Next
       WorksheetExists = Worksheets(WSName).Name = WSName
       On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Sub Button1_Click()
  Dim shname As String, ssname As String
  Dim wb As String, wc As String
  wc = Application.GetOpenFilename
   If wc <> "False" Then Workbooks.Open wc
     Do Until WorksheetExists(ssname)
      ssname = InputBox("Enter sheet name")
       If Not WorksheetExists(ssname) Then
          MsgBox ssname & " doesn't exist!", vbExclamation
       Else
         WSName = ssname

         Sheets(ssname).Select
       End If
       Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: What kind of prompt do you want to achieve? Such that you would be able to select a sheet and then open it?

Comment: @ZygD just a USERFORM which will show all the sheets within activeworkbook so user can select for ex sheet1 or sheet2 or sheet3... just to show the list of worksheet in userform then give the user option to select it

Comment: A userform is just a grey window. It is not a *control*. You cannot list things on a userform just like that. You need to put a control inside your userform. *Controls* are very different - buttons, frames, labels, etc. You could not put a list on any control either. This is why I asked you. I think a Listbox control would be suitable for you. So, just create a userform, insert the listbox and inside `UserForm_Initialize()` put some `ListBox1.AddItem`. And you're done. Put your code here if you run into additional problems.

Comment: @ZygD listbox1.additem won't show the list of worksheets...i want it to show all the worksheets.

Comment: It won't it it's just a sole line. What about combining it with `For` ...`Next` loop? Something like: `For Each ws In Worksheets`
    `ListBox1.AddItem (ws.Name)`
`Next`